# AS3 Flash: Spawning 2 same objects from 1 class?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript, random

I am creating a game in AS3, and in the class file for an enemy's bullet, I have this code.

```
public class enemy2Bullet extends MovieClip
{

    public function enemy2Bullet()
    {
        stop();
        //Setup an event listener to see if the bullet is added to the stage.
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
    }

    private function onAdd(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
        //Now that our object is on the stage, run our custom code.
        init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        if (Math.random() <= 0.5)
        {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bullet2Loop)
        }
        else
        {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bullet2Loop2)
        }
    }

    private function bullet2Loop(e:Event):void
    {
        if (currentLabel != "destroyed")
        {
            this.x += 8;
        }
        if (currentLabel == "destroyedComplete")
        { 
            destroyEnemy2Bullet();
        }
    }

    private function bullet2Loop2(e:Event):void
    {
        if (currentLabel != "destroyed")
        {
            this.x -= 8;
        }
        if (currentLabel == "destroyedComplete")
        {
            destroyEnemy2Bullet();
        }
    }

    public function destroyEnemy2Bullet():void
    {
        {
            //Remove the object from stage
            stage.removeChild(this);
            //Remove any event listeners
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bullet2Loop);
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling, the game runs, but the bullet only shoots in 1 direction.
How can I make it such that the bullets are shot from both left and right, and stay in that direction?

Here's my enemy2 function.

```
private function enemy2Control():void
    {
        if (getTimer() - lastSpawnTime2 > 3000 && aEnemy2Array.length < 3)
        {
            var newEnemy2:MovieClip = new mcEnemy2;
            newEnemy2.x = Math.random() * 800;
            newEnemy2.y = 0;
            aEnemy2Array.push(newEnemy2);
            stage.addChild(newEnemy2);
            lastSpawnTime2 = getTimer();
        }
        //Control enemy's bullets
        for (var i:int = aEnemy2Array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (enemy2LastFire + 750 / (aEnemy2Array.length) < getTimer())

            {
                var currentEnemy2:mcEnemy2 = aEnemy2Array[i];
                if (Math.random() < 0.06)
                {
                    var newEnemy2Bullet:enemy2Bullet = new enemy2Bullet();
                    newEnemy2Bullet.x = currentEnemy2.x;
                    newEnemy2Bullet.y = currentEnemy2.y;
                    enemy2BulletArray.push(newEnemy2Bullet);
                    stage.addChild(newEnemy2Bullet);
                    enemy2LastFire = getTimer();
                }
            }
            for (var j:int = enemy2BulletArray.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                var currentEnemy2Bullet:enemy2Bullet = enemy2BulletArray[j];
                if (currentEnemy2Bullet.y >= stage.stageHeight)
                {
                    enemy2BulletArray.splice(j, 1);
                    currentEnemy2Bullet.destroyEnemy2Bullet();
                }
                if (currentEnemy2Bullet.hitTestObject(playerCore))
                {
                    playerHP -= 1;
                    currentEnemy2Bullet.gotoAndPlay(2);
                    enemy2BulletArray.splice(j, 1);

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: debug the code to see if it ever goes into `bullet2Loop2`

Comment: where does `init()` get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

• You can replace `currentEnemy2Bullet` with `j` and just delete the whole `var currentEnemy2Bullet:enemy2Bullet = enemy2BulletArray[j];` statement.

• `init()` is never called. But it's best if you do the direction calculation and use `newEnemy2Bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, whatever)` within the actual initialization of `newEnemy2Bullet`.

• Truth to be told, your code is fairly messy and can be simplified. For example, you can just determine the direction of the bullet by giving the class a variable, give it a value on initialization, and have the loop update its position based on that variable.

Comment: My bad, init() was called in the previous function. Updated my code.

Comment: I'm getting an error right now, whenever I run the game and get hit by one of these enemies' bullets, I get this

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at enemy2Bullet/destroyEnemy2Bullet()
 at enemy2Bullet/bullet2Loop2()

Comment: @user2036822 That's because you're supposed to remove the event listener before removing the child. You're also supposed to use `splice()` to remove it from the array.

Comment: @user2036822 Also, do remember to close this question once you're finished.

Comment: I knew it was a stupid mistake :/ that's what I get for trying to code at 5am, hahahah. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @user2036822 It happens to the best of us ;)